# How to take screenshot from command line on BBB Angstrom

Tags: beagleboneblack, angstrom-linux

Hi I have a BBB which is running on Angstrom 2013 image. For display purpose I am using a cape which is connected to gpio extensions. There is a Qt application running on BBB, which use to get displayed on the Cape. 
How can I take screenshot of the cape.
I want to take some screen-shot of the running application.
I couldn't find gnome-screenshot on angstrom image, using import command to take screenshot I got an error regarding x11.

How can I get the screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and install [scrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrot)

On Ubuntu based Beagle Bone Black, I installed it as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install scrot
```

To Capture a screenshot:

```
scrot -q 100 /home/debian/Desktop/Desktop.jpg
#-q 100 == best quality
# /home/debian/Desktop/Desktop.jpg is path where to store captured screenshot
```

For more information, you can read [this tutorial here](https://www.tecmint.com/take-screenshots-in-linux-using-scrot/).

Comment: Kindly read the question, I specifically asked for angstrom image.

Comment: @user7345878 I am aware of that,but the process might be similar to what I have above.